# Can a 1st level lizardfolk shifter attack 5 times in one round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization

A lizardfolk recieves the two following abilities:

> Natural Attacks: Bite (1 RP) Lizardfolk gain a natural bite attack, dealing damage equivalent to that of a creature two size categories lower than normal for their size (1d2 for Small races, 1d3 for Medium, etc.). The bite is a primary attack, or a secondary attack if the creature is wielding manufactured weapons.

> Natural Attacks: Claws 2 (RP) Lizardfolk receive two claw attacks. These are primary natural attacks. The damage is based on the creature’s size (1d4 for Medium creatures.)

The shifter has Shifter Claws(su):

> At will, a shifter in her natural form can extend her claws as a swift action to use as a weapon. This magical transformation is fuelled as much by the shifter’s faith in the natural world as it is by inborn talent. The claws on each hand can be used as a primary natural attack, dealing 1d4 points of piercing and slashing damage (1d3 if she is Small). If she uses one of her claw attacks in concert with a weapon held in the other hand, the claw acts as a secondary natural attack instead.

(Alternate Natural Attacks)

> A shifter can draw on her chosen animal aspect to transform her hands into deadly weapons, as represented by the shifter’s claws class feature, but not every animal has prominent claws. The following list provides alternate natural attacks for the shifter claws class feature. Each time the shifter activates her shifter’s claws ability in her natural form, she can manifest one of the alternate natural attacks listed below for any of her chosen aspects, or those that relate to her archetype. Each alternate natural attack replaces one of the shifter’s claw attacks. The shifter can gain up to two different alternate natural attacks with this method. These alternate natural attacks modify only the damage type of the shifter’s natural attacks and otherwise function exactly as the shifter claws class feature.

One example of the alternate natural attacks is the Dragon (Dragonblood Shifter Archetype): Bite (B, P, S), tail slap (B), wing (B)

The shifter could manifest a tail slap and a wing which do not use hands. The crux that I'm most unsure about is whether the clause *and otherwise function exactly as the shifter claws class feature.* means despite being a tail slap, it still "uses" the hand the claw would have done, or not.

Would this mean that, RAW, a lizardfolk shifter could manifest both a tail slap and wing attack for a whopping 5 primary natural attacks at level 1?

Comment: Please don't use code syntax for non-code content. It confuses screen readers for visually impaired and may negatively affect search engines' ability to index your question properly.

Comment: Make sure Lizardfolk is a valid choice in any campaign you'd wish to play such a character in. They're not actually an official [player race](https://www.aonprd.com/Races.aspx?Category=NonCore); d20pfsrd includes them from the *example* of how to use Race Builder points and adds 3rd party content as well. I have allowed them in a game and there wasn't any major issue, but they did outshine the other martial characters for a good 3-5 or more levels, so some GM's may not allow them. A similar race (2 claws or 1 bite/gore) is Skinwalker.

Comment: Tengu can also get both a bite (by default) and two claws (by trading out swordtrained), so it might be a better example than the skinwalker which can only get one or the other. Isn't a lizard, and is a good bit less durable thanks to the CON penalty, but runs closer to the rules in question.

Comment: @sideromancer I'd forgotten about Tengu's alternate trait. I'll switch that in my Answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The combination works

Nothing about Shifter Claws nor Alternate Natural Attacks (including Shifter Aspect) requires giving up use of the hand except the typical rules relating to using Claw [natural attacks](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Natural%20Attacks).

---

On a related note (and copied from my comment), make sure Lizardfolk is a valid choice in any campaign you'd wish to play such a character in. They're not actually an official [player race](https://www.aonprd.com/Races.aspx?Category=NonCore) (and not all races are guaranteed to be allowed anyway); [d20pfsrd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/standard-races-1-10-rp/lizardfolk-8-rp/) includes them from the *example* of how to use Race Builder points and adds 3rd party content as well. I have allowed them in a game and there wasn't any major issue, but they did outshine the other martial characters for a good 3-5 or more levels, a paradigm which doesn't fit all play styles. A similar race (1, presumably primary, bite for 1d3 and alternate racial trait "Claw Attack" gives 2 primary claws for 1d3) is [Tengu](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Tengu).